# How do I query for the cleared status of a transaction using the Quickbooks SDK?

Tags: quickbooks

It's pretty easy to mark a txn as cleared using the QB SDK, but it doesn't look like you can query for this value (to see if it's already cleared for instance).

```
public bool MarkAsCleared(string sTxnID, string sTxnLineID)
{
    // sm is class variable of type QBSessionManager
    IMsgSetRequest msr = sm.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0);
    msr.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

    IClearedStatusMod q = msr.AppendClearedStatusModRq();
    q.ClearedStatus.SetValue(ENClearedStatus.csCleared);
    q.TxnID.SetValue(sTxnID);
    q.TxnLineID.SetValue(sTxnLineID);

    IMsgSetResponse resp = sm.DoRequests(msr);
    if ( resp.ResponseList.Count == 1 && resp.ResponseList.GetAt(0).StatusCode == 0 )
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the VB version for the code posted above. I tested it and it seems to be working. I didn't do the jornal query part. You just pass the TxnID (the listID from your transaction query, txn date and the account list id. The function will return True or False depending on whether or not the txn you pass is cleared for that account.

```
Public Function IsCleared(ByVal sTxnID As String, ByVal dTxnDate As DateTime, ByVal sAccount As String) As Boolean

    Dim bCleared As Boolean = False

    Dim requestMsgSet As IMsgSetRequest
    requestMsgSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 8, 0.0)
    requestMsgSet.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeContinue

    Dim rq As ICustomDetailReportQuery
    rq = requestMsgSet.AppendCustomDetailReportQueryRq()
    rq.CustomDetailReportType.SetValue(ENCustomDetailReportType.cdrtCustomTxnDetail)
    rq.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icClearedStatus)
    rq.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icTxnID)
    ' Is Cleared status per txn or per txn line?
    rq.ReportAccountFilter.ORReportAccountFilter.ListIDList.Add(sAccount)
    rq.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.FromReportDate.SetValue(dTxnDate)
    rq.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate.SetValue(dTxnDate)
    rq.SummarizeRowsBy.SetValue(ENSummarizeRowsBy.srbItemDetail)

    Dim responseMsgSet As IMsgSetResponse
    responseMsgSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(requestMsgSet)

    Dim rp As IReportRet
    rp = responseMsgSet.ResponseList.GetAt(0).Detail

    Try
        Dim data As IORReportData = Nothing
        For i = 0 To rp.ReportData.ORReportDataList.Count - 1
            data = rp.ReportData.ORReportDataList.GetAt(i)
            If (Not data.DataRow Is Nothing) Then
                If (data.DataRow.ColDataList.Count > 1) Then
                    If (data.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(1).value.GetValue() = sTxnID) Then
                        bCleared = (data.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(0).value.GetValue() = "Cleared")
                        Return bCleared
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error looking up cleared status: " + ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Cristina , I need to clear the Journal Line items , i have only Trxdate and Account number, I fallow you Piece of code it's not working for me, it did not give any error but in Datarow always fail (Nothing ), Is there any other solution to clear or Edit the Journal entries please.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hacky way to do it using the CustomDetailReportQuery.  I couldn't figure out a way to just get a report for an individual transaction, so had to do a report on the whole account and then cycle through until you find the right txn and return its cleared status:

```
public bool IsCleared(string sTxnID, string sTxnLineID, string sAccount, out bool bCleared)
{
    bCleared = false;

    IMsgSetRequest msr = sm.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0);
    msr.Attributes.OnError = ENRqOnError.roeStop;

    IJournalEntryQuery cq = msr.AppendJournalEntryQueryRq();
    cq.metaData.SetValue(ENmetaData.mdMetaDataAndResponseData);
    cq.ORTxnQuery.TxnIDList.Add(sTxnID);
    cq.IncludeLineItems.SetValue(true);

    IMsgSetResponse resp = sm.DoRequests(msr);

    try
    {
        IJournalEntryRetList crl = (IJournalEntryRetList)resp.ResponseList.GetAt(0).Detail;
        IJournalEntryRet r = crl.GetAt(0);
        msr.ClearRequests();

        ICustomDetailReportQuery rq = msr.AppendCustomDetailReportQueryRq();
        rq.CustomDetailReportType.SetValue(ENCustomDetailReportType.cdrtCustomTxnDetail);
        rq.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icClearedStatus);
        rq.IncludeColumnList.Add(ENIncludeColumn.icTxnID);

        // Is Cleared status per txn or per txn line?
        rq.ReportAccountFilter.ORReportAccountFilter.FullNameList.Add(sAccount);
        rq.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.FromReportDate.SetValue(r.TxnDate.GetValue());
        rq.ORReportPeriod.ReportPeriod.ToReportDate.SetValue(r.TxnDate.GetValue());
        rq.SummarizeRowsBy.SetValue(ENSummarizeRowsBy.srbItemDetail);

        resp = sm.DoRequests(msr);
        IReportRet rp = (IReportRet)resp.ResponseList.GetAt(0).Detail;
        IORReportData data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < rp.ReportData.ORReportDataList.Count; i++)
        {
            data = rp.ReportData.ORReportDataList.GetAt(i);
            if (data.DataRow != null)
            {
                if (data.DataRow.ColDataList.Count > 1)
                {
                    if (data.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(1).value.GetValue() == sTxnID)
                    {
                        bCleared = (data.DataRow.ColDataList.GetAt(0).value.GetValue() == "Cleared");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log("Error looking up cleared status: " + e.Message);
    }
    return false;
}
```